# Gitlab repo cloning to Cloudbees CI

Tags: cloudbees

I am unable to clone gitlab repo to Cloudbees CI. I want to integrate both. Anyone help?

I have tried adding credentials ( api token and usename with password as well. But still unable to clone and getting the error as Error cloning the repo